# How to test google market place api with php

Tags: php, google-play-services, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use this api http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/. I would like to get some that from play store. like App name, description, screenshots and download rating(total downloads, week downloads....)

I'm using the php version. I uploaded all the code to my personal server. www.example.com/test/. 
Should I configure anything else in addition of local.php, email and password fields? I only did that.

I have this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'HTTP request returned code 400' in /homepages/31/d229886149/htdocs/carlos/test/Market/MarketSession.php:212 Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/31/d229886149/htdocs/carlos/test/Market/MarketSession.php(160): MarketSession->executeRawHttpQuery('??????DQAAAMkAA...')
#1 /homepages/31/d229886149/htdocs/carlos/test/Market/MarketSession.php(147): MarketSession->executeProtobuf(Object(Request))
#2 /homepages/31/d229886149/htdocs/carlos/test/examples/test_categories.php(15): MarketSession->execute(Object(Request_RequestGroup))
#3 {main} thrown in /homepages/31/d229886149/htdocs/carlos/test/Market/MarketSession.php
```

on line 212

Thank you.

After that I would like to implement it with codeIgniter

Answer (score 1):

try with '0123456789123456' as an ANDROID_DEVICEID

```
define('GOOGLE_EMAIL','someone@gmail.com');
define('GOOGLE_PASSWD','SomePassword');
define('ANDROID_DEVICEID','0123456789123456');
```